# DNN underestimates high values

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm running a DNN on a dataset in order to predict the output values (y). The actual vs fitted graph shows a slight overestimation of the small values and an underestimation of the higher values.
[image]

The activation function I used in each layer is the Relu function and the Loss is a simple MSE. I tried to compare the distributions of the actual values and the fitted.
[image]

My questions are:

1. What can i deduce from the second plot that i don't already know from the first?
2. In order to gain a better fit i was thinking of assigning a weight to the high y values in the training set or duplicating them. But isn't this method "cheating"?

Comment: How do you know your features are informative?

Comment: @Sycorax The only available features i have are measurements coming from a segmented 3D cube. Basically every feature is a different x,y,z coordinate, each one containing a real value for every different observation. Is there a way to check if this kind of features are informative?

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/603435/247274)